# Prioritising a newsfeed using Elasticsearch and Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm just getting started with Elasticsearch and want to implement a prioritised newsfeed for users based on their interests.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.5, Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.0 and Elasticsearch 6.4.2

I have loaded some sample news topics into Elasticsearch and implemented a findByKeywords repository method which returns the topics ordered by created date.

What I want to do now is prioritise and score the news topics further. For example:

1. Users rate their interests from 1 to 5. Interests with a higher rating would be displayed higher in the news feed.
2. Topics with a higher user engagement
3. What device the user is using
   etc.

What would be the best way to build this scoring logic with Elasticsearch? Ideally I would like the returned results to be paginated and ordered like the findAll method returns its results.

Additionally, would I need to keep track of what items the user has last seen to prevent having to search all news items again.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not an expert in `spring` but even if I was, I think your question is too broad and missing what you tried so far. I suggest you will add some examples of your data and the code you tried. Good luck anyway

Comment: you can use the [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and the [weight score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight) to get some working

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is usually a use case for a Multidimensional OLAP solution. To do this with elastic you need to denormalize your data. Add everything to one index. This way you can filter and sort as you need without ristrictions. This way you sacrifice space for usability.

Good Luck!